# Remove a substring in XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a huge number of XML files that I need to modify
With this example file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<element1>
  <element2>
    <element3 attribute="X:\a\b\c\any string.xyz\name.ext" />
  </element2>
</element1>
```

I want to use XSLT to process the part starting with 'X:\a\b\c' followed by any string and ending with '.xyz\name.ext'.
Here I want to remove the '\any sting.xyz' part where 'any string' can be any string
The proper result should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<element1>
  <element2>
    <element3 attribute="X:\a\b\c\name.ext" />
  </element2>
</element1>
```

I have tried a lot of solutions. This one results in <element3 attribute='name.ext>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Identity template to copy all elements and attributes -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Modify the 'attribute' attribute of element3 -->
  <xsl:template match="element3/@attribute">
    <xsl:attribute name="attribute">
      <!-- Keep only the part after the last '\' -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(., 'X:\a\b\c\'), '\')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153)?

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the string starts with a constant prefix, then you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="element3/@attribute">
    <xsl:variable name="prefix">X:\a\b\c\</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:attribute name="attribute">
        <xsl:value-of select="$prefix"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(., $prefix), '\')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```